# Need help removing ambiguity from grammar

Tags: context-free, compilers

$E \rightarrow UV \bracevert EBE \bracevert V \bracevert [E]$

$V \rightarrow a \bracevert b$

$U \rightarrow < \bracevert > $

$B \rightarrow ? \bracevert ! \bracevert @ $

Order of precedence: $?$ < $!$ < $@$, with unary operators ($<, >$) being the highest

$?$, $!$, $@$ are right associative.

My attempt:

$E \rightarrow UV \bracevert EBT \bracevert V \bracevert [E] $

$T \rightarrow E$

$V \rightarrow a \bracevert b$

$U \rightarrow < \bracevert > $

$ B \rightarrow ? \bracevert B_1 $

$ B_1 \rightarrow ! \bracevert B_2 $

$ B_2 \rightarrow @ $

I'm not sure if I left out some corner cases during my conversion. Appreciate if you guys can point some mistakes out and offer some hints.

Comment: Why do you think the original grammar is ambiguous?

Comment: I can reproduce two different parse trees using left-most derivations using "a!a!a"

Comment: It seems that questions like "Please check my solution" are off-topic here, but the rule $T\  \to \  E$ gets you back where you were: (1) $E \to EBT \to VBT \to_* a!T \to a!E \to_* a!a!a!$ and (2) $E \to EBT \to EBTBT \to_* a!a!a!$. I used $\to_*$ as a shorthand for multi-step rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt put $T\rightarrow UV \ \bracevert\  V\  \bracevert\  [E]$ instead of $T\rightarrow E$.

The idea is not to just replace symbols arbitrarily, but replace in such a way that it's derivations are a subset of possible derivations (which should be unambiguous).

And you can also use the procedure prescribed in textbooks or in Jonathan's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106195/converting-ambiguous-grammar-to-unambiguous to remove ambiguity (unless the language in inherently ambiguous). I like Jonathan Leffler's answers because he gives lot of detail as well as intuition behind answers.